# Changing the text of the Fragment in the ViewPager

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

```
@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    CharacterFragment fragment = new CharacterFragment();
    View rootView = fragment.getView();
    TextView character = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.character);
    character.setText(name[position]);
    return fragment;
}
```

This is my code for changing the fragment in the `ViewPager`. The fragment just has a single text view. basically, I am just siwping through the alphabets in my name. So, depending on the index, I have to set the text in the `TextView` of the fragment.

With the above code, the programs blows with a `NullPointerException` because the layout has not been inflated yet, so I presume.

What would be the right way to change the content of the `Fragment`? **Is there a callback method that would let me know that it has become visible ?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no callback. You could send the text as a parameter to the fragment when you're creating it and set the text inside of the fragment.

Something like:

```
@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    CharacterFragment fragment = CharacterFragment.newInstance(name[position]);
    View rootView = fragment.getView();
    return fragment;
}
```

your `CharacterFragment.newInstance(String name)` method would look like:

```
public static CharacterFragment.newInstance(String name) {
    CharacterFragment fragment = new CharacterFragment();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.put("NAME_ARG", name);
    fragment.setArguments(args);
    return fragment;
}
```

then in your `onCreateView()` you get the arguments through `getArguments()` method and you get the string with key `NAME_ARG`. And you have it! Makes sense?

Comment: The problem is the reference to the `TextView` always comes back as null. I tried using `getView().findViewById(R.id.myTextView)` in the `onResume()` of the fragment but the returned value is always null.

Comment: Edited the answer to provide more details. The idea is to send the string as a parameter when creating the fragment and then in `onCreateView` you get the String from parameters and set it to the TextView.

Comment: Works ! One quick question: How do I make the text big enough so that each character fills the screen, no matter what size the screen is ? :)

Comment: I don't understand ... You want to make each fragment to fill the screen and to contain only a letter?

Comment: Yes. Basically, I am just making a simple example to learn `ViewPager`. That's all.

Answer (score 1):

That's not the correct way to use `getView()`. The way to accomplish what you want is a little different. In order to do so you should pass the string (in this case `name[position]`) to the method. **But you should remember that Fragments are not supposed to be instantiated with their constructor, instead create a static method, I'll show you:**

```
@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    CharacterFragment fragment = CharacterFragment.newInstance(name[position]);
    return fragment;
}
```

And then, inside `CharacterFragment.java`

```
public static CharacterFragment newInstance(String name) {
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putString("key_name",name);

    CharacterFragment fragment = new CharacterFragment();
    CharacterFragment.setsetArguments(bundle);

    return fragment;
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

     View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_xml_file, container, false);

     // AND HERE WE GO
     String name = getArguments().getString("key_name");
     TextView character= view.findViewById(R.id.character);
     character.setText(name);

     return view;
}
```

Comment: *Fragments are not supposed to be instantiated with their constructor* The online course offered by University of Maryland shows the way I do it, by using `new` :O